# Why don't `stty -a` list `raw` in its output, when any modern shell, like Bash, is said to operate in raw mode?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Why don't `stty -a` list `raw` in its output, when any modern shell, like Bash, is said to operate in raw mode?

I understand that any modern shell should operate in raw mode, i.e:

- Input made available character by character.
- Echoing is disabled.
- All special processing of terminal input and ouput is disabled.

and that Readline processes user input.

So, why isn't `raw` listed in the output from `stty -a`?

Comment: 1. raw is not a tty flag, but a combination setting, which will turn other flags on and off. stty -a only tells you which flags are on and which are off. 2. the commands run from the shell get a "cooked" not a raw terminal -- either cat or stty. 3. only the bash shell is using readline. 4. readline will change the terminal back to "cooked" when the user has finished editing. 5. your Q looks artificial, sorry.

Comment: @pizdelect - is there any way I could see the current terminal mode for Bash, e.g. raw or cooked? Why does Readline change the terminal back to "cooked"? Doesn't it stay "raw" for Bash? Otherwise, Readline will not get input before the user presses a newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that *raw mode* is a bit of an approximation. There's no official definition of *raw mode* and in practice it means different things for different APIs.

What they meant is that shells like `bash` that  implement their own line editor disable *some* of the features of the tty line discipline. In particular, they need to disable the line discipline's own line editor (`icanon` setting aka `-cbreak`) and local `echo`. They don't disable some other line discipline features like the sending of SIGINT upon `^C` (`isig` setting).

`stty -a` reports the individual discrete termios settings (like those `icanon`, `echo`, `isig` above).

`stty` also supports a few aliases to *set* more than one setting at a time like `sane`, `cooked` or... *`raw`*.

`stty raw` disables all tty line discipline features except `echo`. So there are features it disables (like `isig`) that `bash` doesn't for its line editor and it doesn't disable `echo` while `bash` does.

The manual of the GNU implementation of `stty` describes `raw` as being equivalent to `-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon  -ixoff  -icanon  -opost  -isig  -iuclc  -ixany -imaxbel -xcase min 1 time 0`. That's the set of discrete `termios` settings that `stty raw` tweaks (leaving the other ones alone).

Note that `opost` is not a `stty` alias, it's a discrete tty line discipline setting of its own but it affects all other output post-processing settings like `onlcr`, `olcuc`. Or in other words `onlcr`/`olcuc` are ineffective if `opost` is not on which explains why `stty raw` doesn't bother turning off all those output processing features.

Some systems have `cfmakeraw()` / `cfmakesane()` libc functions that can also set more than one setting at once. The `cfmakeraw()` of the GNU libc at least is different from GNU's `stty raw` in that for instance it disables `echo` and doesn't disable `iuclc` or `ixoff`.

Comment: Thank you. So, is the raw mode described by `man termios` by any means related to the `raw` combination setting of `stty`? In particular, while `man termios` describes canonical and raw modes with respect to how input is made available, either line-by-line or char-by-char, respectively, will the settings of `stty` change how input is made available (e.g. `stty icanon` or `stty raw`), or do they only affect the line discipline (handling of special characters, signals etc.)?

Comment: @Shuzheng, if you're referring to `cfmakeraw()`, that's yet a different set of settings. In any case, that's **all** about  the tty line discipline. `icanon`/`isig` are all configuration of the tty line discipline. They  are not applicable and wouldn't make sense when using a difference line discipline like SLIP (IP over serial) or serial mouse driver.

Comment: @Shuzheng, see also [What are the responsibilities of each Pseudo-Terminal (PTY) component (software, master side, slave side)?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/117981) for more context.

Comment: StéphaneChazelas - but, will setting `stty icanon` but the terminal in "canonical mode" as described by `man termios`? The `icanon` setting (`stty`) only enables the following characters: `erase, kill, werase, rprnt`, but it doesn't say whether the input will be made available line-by-line?

Comment: @Shuzheng the "Canonical and noncanonical mode" are described in the [`termios(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) manpage in the section with the same name. Just read it.

Comment: @Shuzheng, `icanon` enables the tty line discipline line editor which does make use of the `erase`, `kill`, `werase`, `eol`, `eof`... character settings (the configuration of that editor)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yes, but while I can see that input is made available char-by-char for `stty raw` by virtue of `min 1 time 0`, how can I see from `man stty` that `stty icanon` will buffer input until it receives a newline (i.e. input is made available line-by-line)? The enabling of `erase, kill, werase, rprnt` doesn't directly reflects this, does it? This is why I'm confused.

Comment: @Shuzheng,  `min 1 time 0` doesn't apply when `icanon` is on. Again, `icanon` enables the line editor (so obviously applications will only read the output of that editor (the edited line) when it's submitted with the `eol` or `eol2` or `eof` settings). The `min` and `time` settings only make sense when *not* using that editor. The `erase`/`kill` are not settings you enable or disable, that's key-binding settings for that line editor, equivalent to the `bind`s of `bash`'s readline editor if you like, the difference is that line editor is much cruder and is implemented in the kernel.